# Reset bootstrap drop down list

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to reset bootstrap drop down with placeholder but it's not working.Here is my declaration,

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_emp_type_involved">
    <label for="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" class="col-md-4 control-label">Type</label>
        <div class="col-md-7">
            <select data-placeholder="Select type" id="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" name="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" class="chosen-select">
            Option 1
            Option 2
            </select>
        </div>
</div>
```

On button click I am trying,

```
$("#sri_EmpTypeInvolved").addclass("placeholder","select type");
```

But it's not working. What would be correct way to achieve the same ?

Comment: Try `.addClass`. Javascript is case-sensitive

Comment: If you are looking to change the `data-placeholder` attribute, use `$("#sri_EmpTypeInvolved").attr('data-placeholder', 'select type')`

Comment: Tried above but not working..@MattO'Connell

Comment: What are you trying to add 'select type' to? The `select` element?

Comment: @MattO'Connell , "Select type" is the placeholder text which I would like put on button click.

Answer (score 1):

If you're trying to set a placeholder for your dropdown list, here's how you'd do it:

```
<div class="form-group" id="div_emp_type_involved">
    <label for="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" class="col-md-4 control-label">Type</label>
    <div class="col-md-7">
        <select data-placeholder="Select type" id="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" name="sri_EmpTypeInvolved" class="chosen-select">
            <option disabled selected>Select Type</option>
            <option>1</option>
            <option>2</option>
         </select>
    </div>
 </div>
```

If you need to change it on a button click:

```
$('button').click(function(){
    $('#div_emp_type_involved option').eq(0).text('some new placeholder text');
})
```

Comment: it's definitely working. you need to describe the problem more clearly